# Test multiple fetches in componentDidMount with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, fetch, jestjs, enzyme

I am starting to learn more about testing for React using Jest/Enzyme and I am trying to learn how to test api calls that use fetch.

I have a fetch call in a `componentDidMount()` method and I am able to test that correctly. In the `beforeEach()` method, I have a `window.fetch` method that creates the mock fetch. Here is an example:

```
beforeEach(() => {
mockData = /* mock data */
// mock fetch call  
window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
  json: () => Promise.resolve({
    data: mockData,
  })
}));
component = shallow(<Component />);
});
```

However, I have another component that has two fetch calls in the `componentDidMount()` method, and I'm wondering how I can mock each fetch call individually.  Is it possible to have two `window.fetch` calls or somehow pass in a url for the fetch?

I am still new to this, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock) library to mock each request separately. Suppose you're requesting 2 URLs and you want to return `mockData` in the request to the first URL, and just 404 status in the second one. Your example code mocked with fetch-mock may look like this:

```js
import fetchMock from "fetch-mock";

beforeEach(() => {
  mockData = { /* mock data */ };
  fetchMock.mock("/first/url", mockData);
  fetchMock.mock("/second/url", 404);
  component = shallow(<Component />);
});

/* You should also restore the original fetch in afterEach */
afterEach(() => {
  fetchMock.restore();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This looks like what I'm looking for :), question. for the second fetchMock call, can I also have other mock data to put in there as well?

Comment: is there no way to do this without fetch-mock?

Comment: You could use any library to mock HTTP responses, e.x. msw